# Assigning 60 kids to 20 rooms with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

**Update: Still I didn't get a correct answer**

---

I have the following problem:

> Given $60$ kids and $20$ rooms where each room has $4$ seats, what's the number of possibilities to order them such that no room is empty?

I tried to simplify my problem by saying we need to choose 20 kids from 60. and to divide them into the rooms (each in one room) then with the left 40 we need to divide them into 20 rooms that the maximum a room can take is 3 kids.

But, I wasn't able to solve the second part.
Note: the order of seats and the order of rooms is important (all different)
maybe inclusion-exclusion may help here?

Comment: Are the kids distinguishable? Usually they aren’t...

Comment: @Tavish yes they are

Comment: Are the order of the children in the seats in each classroom considered a "different order"? Or is *Child 1 in seat 1 of Classroom 3, Child 4 in seat 2 of Classroom 3* the "same order" as *Child 4 in seat 1 of Classroom 3, Child 1 in seat 2 of Classroom 3*?

Comment: it's not the same each seat has unique number and each room too

Comment: @AdamRubinson could you help me please?

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't say that in the question, and it seems a bit much to count these as two possibilities: having everything else the same in all classrooms except one, but swapping two kids' places in just that one classroom... Basically if you require order in each classroom then suddenly the problem becomes really difficult. At least, difficult for me.

Comment: @clark_smith Do you know the answer? If yes,can you tell us?

Comment: @Tavish sorry I don't, someone told me (inclusion and exclusion may be helpful...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of ways to distribute the kids are $80\times 79 \times 78....\times21= \frac{80!}{20!}$.

We will subtract from these the cases where atleast one room is empty. Clearly, atmost $5$ rooms can be empty at once. By inclusion-exclusion, the said number of ways will be

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 {20 \choose k}\cdot (-1)^{k+1} \cdot \frac{(80-4k)!}{(20-4k)!} $$
Giving us the answer:

$$\frac{80!}{20!} - \sum_{k=1}^5 {20 \choose k}\cdot (-1)^{k+1} \cdot \frac{(80-4k)!}{(20-4k)!} =$$

[image]

Comment: how did you calculate the first line? could you explain please?

Comment: @clark_smith Child $1$ has $80$ seats available, child $2$ has $79$ seats available, and so on till child $60$.

Comment: just a small note: using inclusion-exclusion you should write (-1)^k not (-1)^(k+1)

Comment: @clark_smith No, the odd $k$ terms should be positive in this case.

Comment: You are right, to summarise I wasn't able to solve this (even though I knew the idea) is that I didn't know to to calculate the possibilities to divide 60 kids into 80 seats and similar cases

Comment: Actually, I don't think I would have got the answer. I used the same method of subtracting cases where at least 1 room is empty. However, my way would have included repeat cases. I don't really know inclusion-exclusion well (although I *kind of* get the general idea- I just haven't learned how to apply it). I'm guessing inclusion-exclusion ensures there are no repeat cases.

Comment: like, can you explain the first sum please? I get where 20 choose k comes from, but the (-1)^k and the other bit I don't quite get.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It’s a way to compute the union of multiple events without repetition, and involves alternating sign changes (you should look it up). As for the factorials, when we are excluding $k$ rooms, there are $80-4k$ seats available, and then it’s similar to how I calculated the total number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to solve the equation $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{20}=60$$ where $1\leq a_i\leq 4$ for all $i$

Make a polynomial $$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{20}=x^{20}(1+x)^{20}(1+x^2)^{20}$$ and calculate coefficient at $x^{60}$ and multiply it with $60!$.

Comment: it's not the same problem, I have order in rooms...

Comment: Sorry you don't understand.